# Glasswire Alternative for Linux? CLI or GUI

Tags: linux, network-monitor, bandwidth

Is there an ***Glasswire*** Alternative for Linux to monitor Internet bandwidth usage of running programs?

CLI or GUI will be fine.

*Edit:*

One that can monitor running program/process, say Firefox or Chrome. How many MB they have consumed (each). I've found ***iftop*** but it don't display the programs (and the total bandwidth for each). And ***NetHog*** on the other hand display Total bandwidth per second.

Here is an ***GlassWire*** capture, If that may help:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with NetHog using: `sudo nethogs -v 3`

See my [answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1291285/227233).

> You can use nethog with total bandwidth monitored per MB since it
>   started with:
>
> `sudo nethogs -v 3`